c# call event from derived custom control panel
i have made a custom control which uses the OnGotFocus event and it work without issues.
I have made a second class which inherited this class and has its own OnGotFocus method. Not i want that the OnGotFocus method from the inherited class should called when OnGotFocus occures but only the base class mehtod is called. How can i change this?
Thx
  public partial class MyJobPanel : Panel
  {
    public MyJobPanel()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
      this.BackColor = Color.SandyBrown;
      _isSelected = true;
      base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {

      this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
      _isSelected=false;
      base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }
  }

  public class MyJobTypeToolchange : MyJobPanel
  {
    public MyJobTypeToolchange() : base()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        // I want to call this method!!!
      base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }

    public override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
      // I want to call this method!!!
      base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }
  }


Can you fix you sample so it it at least theoretical able to be compiled? _isSelected isn't defined, a panel isn't focusable by default, you can't increase visibility from protected to public just like that.

It looks like you forgot to specify partial in your sub class, which means it won't be linked to the other class part of the panel. Adding partial to the declaration of MyJobTypeToolchange should fix your problem.

What "markup". This should be Winforms.

Markup might be the wrong term, but as far as I can tell from the question, it could be WPF, which uses XAML as the other class part. I will reword to be less confusing.

Thanks, that's the solution! Many thanks!
